# AEM 6.5 Page Properties Cancel button not working the firs time you open it?

Tags: aem

The Page Properties **Cancel** button is not working. Clicking on it the Editor should return to the previous View but it doesn't do anything and just stays on the same page (which is Page Properties).

I am refering to the Cancel button in the picture below.

[image]

And this is the element in question:

```
<coral-actionbar-item class="coral3-ActionBar-item">
<a id="shell-propertiespage-closeactivator" class="betty-ActionBar-item foundation-fixedanchor foundation-backanchor coral3-Button coral3-Button--quiet" href="https://author-instance/mnt/overlay/wcm/core/content/sites/properties.html?item=%2Fcontent%2Fsomethi..." is="coral-anchorbutton" variant="quiet" data-foundation-backanchor-form="cq-sites-properties-form" size="M" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><coral-anchorbutton-label>Cancel</coral-anchorbutton-label></a>
</coral-actionbar-item>
```

Any suggestions how to go about fixing this issue?

Here are my console logs.
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Update:**

I was able to reasearch the issue further.

The issue appears only the first time you open Page Properties for any Page (using any Templates) when Session Storage and Cookies are cleared. The Cancel button will produce the error below and the href for the Cancel button will point to itself.

After you go back with Browser back and open any subsequent Page Properties the Cancel button works correctly and points to the previous View.

I was able to determine that the Cancel error appears only with AEM 6.5 SP12 with spring4shell fix and AEM 6.5 SP11 but not with AEM 6.5 SP7.

The AEM 6.5 SP7 is the version with the popup when you first open the Editor console.
[image]

The customisation I found in the code is in the picure below.

[image: .]

Comment: Have you tried restart your instance and checkeds ome permissions?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added the update to the initial issue above.

Comment: If you are able to replicate the issue without your custom code, that is, in a vanilla instance, then, it should be reported to Adobe Care. Otherwise, if only happens when your deploy your project, I would look first for customizations and/or overlays to the touch UI elements.

Comment: Hi @ronnyfm I was not able to reproduce the issue on the vanilla instance with the same SP. It only happens when I deploy our custom project. 
Can you please suggest what overlays would you check for this. I found only the customisation that I included as picutre in the initial ticket.

Comment: I would start by removing the directory folder, and then, the picker, I suspect one of these two are the customization causing this. Eventually, you can remove all of them and/or review what is being accomplished with them.

Comment: Hi @ronnyfm Thanks for your feedback. I removed directory folder and picker and installed the bundle but the issue did not go away.